# Cast JSONObject to JSONArray. Problems with UTF8 characters

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to cast a `JSONObject` to `JSONArray`. The `JSONObject` contains an object of type `JSONArray`. The array is a sequence of strings. One of the strings in the sequence is formatted as the following.

```
"uid=\u00d1\u0088\u00d1\u0084\u00d1\u0088"
```

after doing a cast of the `JSONObject` to an array the characters in the array change.

```
"uid=???" T
```

After the cast to `JSONArray` the original double byte characters in the above `\u` format change to the incorrect display characters in my java program. Any ideas? Has anyone seen this problem? I have done some searching but have not come up with answers to my problem.

The code below is what't used to do this.

```
public static String[] read(JSONObject input)
{
     com.ibm.TEPS.JSON.Any.assertTypeCode(input, _type);

     JSONArray val = (JSONArray)input.get(FW_Properties.TEPSREST_TYPE_EXT_VAL);  

     String [] result = new String[val.size()];

     for(int i = 0;i<result.length;i++)
     {
        result[i] = (String)val.get(i);
     }

     return result;
  }
```

Comment: To my knowledge JSONObject and JSONArray are two different classes, and you can't cast between them.  You can of course fetch an element in a JSONObject which is an JSONArray, but that is not casting one to the other.  (And better to use `getJSONArray` to do that.)

Comment: The value of the `uid` element in the JSONObject is 3 double-byte characters.  "???" is probably the only way to print them in your current environment.  (It looks like "c" with a "beard",  "a" with a double dot, and another "c" with a "beard".)

Comment: (Or maybe that's "e" with a hat, rather than "c" with a beard.)

Comment: it not casting what you are doing, you are reading a JsonArray from a JsonObject

Comment: Thanks for the responses. The UID string value are russian (Cyrilllic) characters in an LDAP distinguished name. шфш

Comment: The get method is retrieving a JSON array from the JSON object. The JSON libraries I am using unfortunately don't have a getJSONArray call in the JSONObject API. So the only way to convert to the JSONArray object is the cast notation.

Comment: Here are the hex UTF 8 bytes for the 3 Cyrillic letters above. D1 88 D1 84 D1 88. The ??? happens when I copy and paste from my editor. So the original string in the JSON object appears to be the correct utf8 bytes for this string. It then changes when I try to convert to the JSONArray.